# RubyMine and RVM, not detecting Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I've followed the guidelines [here][1]

I have `rvm` set to use the `ruby-2.3.0@rails4.2` as the default.  The app is working.  However, I wanted to use RubyMine as I enjoy JetBrains other IDEs.

However, even though rails is installed, and going into `settings>Ruby SDK and Gems`, I have it set to use my default I think.  I have a checkmark under the `rails4.2` entry under the `RVM:ruby-2.3.0` entry.  Checking the gem list to the right, it shows Rails and ActiveRecord.  However, when I'm in my project and I have a model file pulled it, it says that it cannot find ActiveRecord, it also can't find validates, etc.

However, when I make changes and save, and run the app, everything works as I've changed it.  RM also states that it all gems necessary for the project and if I want to let it install.  If I choose yes, it states bundler is not installed, and if I would like to install it and then the gems needed.  If I select yes, nothing seems to happen after the progress bar elapses.

While my code does seem to work, I'd like to try and get this resolved so that only real errors show up.  Any ideas or suggestions?  Thanks!

Edit: Bundler version is 1.11.2
Rubymine version 8.0.3

Ok, I've done a little bit more looking around, and still haven't found anything that works.  Tried making sure my .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset files were formatted correctly, and they are.  From all appearances, it's reading the right gemset.  I've included my environment gemset output below.

```
    RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.2
RUBY VERSION: 2.3.0 (2015-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/brg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails4.2
USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/brg/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/brg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby
EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/brg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails4.2/bin
SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/brg/.gem/specs
SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/brg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/etc
RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  ruby
  x86_64-linux
GEM PATHS:
   /home/brg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails4.2
   /home/brg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global
GEM CONFIGURATION:
   :update_sources => true
   :verbose => true
   :backtrace => false
   :bulk_threshold => 1000
   "gem" => "--no-document"
REMOTE SOURCES:
   https://rubygems.org/
SHELL PATH:
   /home/brg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin
   /home/brg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails4.2/bin
   /home/brg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin
   /home/brg/.rvm/bin
   /usr/local/sbin
   /usr/local/bin
   /usr/sbin
   /usr/bin
   /sbin
   /bin
   /usr/games
   /usr/local/games
   /home/brg/.rvm/bin
----------------------
IDE: RubyMine 8.0.3, build #RM-143.1559
OS: Linux 3.19.0-32-generic[amd64]
Java: 1.7.0_95-b00
RubyMine SDK Environment:
Sdk: RVM: ruby-2.3.0 [rails4.2]
Sdk Version: ver.2.3.0p0 ( revision 53290) p0
Ruby Interpreter: /home/brg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby
RVM Sdk: yes, gemset:rails4.2
RVM Home: /home/brg/.rvm
Sdk Language Level: 2.2
Sdk Load Path:
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux
     /opt/RubyMine-8.0.3/rubystubs22
Sdk Gem paths: 
     ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails4.2/bundler/gems
     ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails4.2/gems
     ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems
Gems used for 'things_i_bought':
```

`  [1]: http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html

Comment: What is the output of bundler -v  ?

Comment: Bundler version is 1.11.2